# "The delegation will depart and will be accompanied" vs. "will depart and be accompanied"

Tags: syntactic-analysis, auxiliary-verbs, parallelism, ellipses

> (a) The delegation will depart from the embassy at 9 A.M. and **will** be accompanied to the airport by the Minister of Sports.
>
> (b) The delegation will depart from the embassy at 9 A.M. and be accompanied to the airport by the Minister of Sports.

I have two questions about modal-verb ellipsis.

1. Can we omit the boldfaced modal verb in (a), without changing the meaning of the sentence?
2. Which sounds more natural, (a) or (b)?

Comment: Neither. “The delegation will depart the embassy for the airport at 9ᴀᴍ, accompanied by the minister of sports.”

Comment: "Can we omit the boldfaced modal verb in (a)?" Not in this case, at least. "Which sounds more natural?" (a), of course, (b) sounds difficult to parse and almost ambiguous.

Comment: @tchrist That doesn't mean the same thing as (a) or (b).

Comment: @Kris Of course it does.

Comment: Nor is that the OP's point.

Comment: Both sound fine to my native speaker ear:) Both seem completely theoretically possible. It's just a coordination of entire Verb Phrases or of the lower verb phrases complementing the phrasal verb.

Comment: One of thousands of such sentences from the web: *You'll stay in quality accommodation and be accompanied every step of the way by an expert Travel Director*.

Comment: I cannot see the objections to either. My native speaker's ear is like Araucaria's; both sentences seem possible and, to me, natural.

Answer (score 1):

1 - Yes
2 - (B); no need to repeat, sounds weird in normal conversation